# how to allow ssh connections to server only from local UFW

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vpn, ufw

I have  Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64 droplet on digital ocean. I have set up open.vpn and ufw on it. UFW blocks all ssh connections. I would like it to allow ssh connections from computers which use this server vpn service. 
How to do it?

I have tried to `ufw allow from <server ip>` but that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this syntax with UFW:

```
ufw allow from 192.168.0.4 to any port 22
```

(more info on UFW here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)

Which will allow an IP address or port. Depending on your VPN configuration, you may need to allow whatever network you have setup with OpenVPN (i.e. a 172.16.xxx.xxx network, possibly).

You might also need to reconfigure openSSH and change what address/interface it's listening on. There is some useful information on the ListenAddress directive here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap15sec122.html

A few more things to check:
- SSH over VPN works when ufw is off?
- SSH works from localhost (try to SSH after already connected through console or SSH)?
- you can connect to other services running over VPN (if you have a web server, for instance)--I believe there is a kernel option that allows interfaces to communicate with each other that might not be enabled (see the section where it mentions IP forwarding http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/07/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-router.html)
- what error are you getting when you try to SSH? (is it a connection timeout, some sort of deny error, etc)

Comment: 1. ufw diisabled, openvpn enabled - > ssh works fine 
2. ufw enabled -> ssh doesn’t work
3. I would like to allow ssh connections only for openvpn clients but I can't figure how to do it.  
I get time out error. I can see in ufw.log that it was blocked.

Comment: Please post ufw log and openvpn configuration as well as "ip addr" output